# Grails 3.3.11 Integration Test (GrailsApplication)

Tags: grails

I am now in trouble with the configuration variable GrailsApplication in my Integration Tests. I don't know why, but, I am not managing to get its value when testing my api. I am using Grails 3.3.11. The value of the variable is being null and, due to it, I can't authenticate to perform the tests. I would appreciate your help. I am using Grails 3.3.11.

```
package br.com.xxx.id.test.integration

//Imports were moved out to simplify understanding

class IdControllerSpec extends Specification {
    def grailsApplication
    @Value('${local.server.port}')
    Integer serverPort
    String accessToken
    String baseUrl
    JSONObject documentPropertiesForTesting
    JSONObject documentForTesting
    String partTest
    String userTest
    String typeIdTest
    String refreshToken

    void setup(){
        baseUrl = "http://localhost:${serverPort}/cmbid/api/v1"
        partTest = "partTest"
        
    }

void "Saving a new and valid document properties"() {
        when:
            refreshToken = grailsApplication.config.getProperty('refreshToken')
            accessToken = "Bearer " + authenticateXxxAut()
            documentPropertiesForTesting = createNewTestDocumentProperties()
            typeIdTest = documentPropertiesForTesting.get("message").toString().substring(20,52)

        then:
            documentPropertiesForTesting.get("status") == "ok"
            documentPropertiesForTesting.get("message").contains("properly saved!")

        cleanup:
            DocumentProperties.withNewSession {
                def dp = DocumentProperties.findById(typeIdTest)
                dp.delete(flush: true)
            }
    }

def authenticateXxxAut() {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        String response = ""
        try {
            JSONObject responseBody
            println('****************************')
            println(grailsApplication.config.getProperty('aut.newTokenUrl'))
            println(grailsApplication.config.getProperty('refreshToken)'))
            println('****************************')

            def httpPost = new HttpPost(grailsApplication.config.getProperty('aut.newTokenUrl') + grailsApplication.config.getProperty('refreshToken)'))
            CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost)

            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                responseBody = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()))
                response = responseBody.get("access_token")
            } else {
                response = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode().toString()
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            print(e.getLocalizedMessage())
        } finally {
            httpClient.close()
            return response
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are having problems with `serverPort`, you want to reference that in a method marked with `@OnceBefore`.

Comment: More info available at https://guides.grails.org/grails-controller-testing/guide/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I've been upgrading a Grails `2.x` app to version `3.3.11` and just referencing the (provided) variable `serverPort` worked for me. The IDE shows it as being uninitialized but running the tests, it gets the correct value assigned. I also have my test classes annotated with `@Integration(applicationClass = Application.class)`.

Here's how I get the URL to point against:

```
def url = "http://localhost:${serverPort}${grailsApplication.config.getProperty('server.contextPath', String, '')}"
```